# Symfony 4 Authentication with JSON

Tags: php, json, api, symfony4

I'm following this [guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/json_login_setup.html) to make a Json authentication endpoint but am getting stuck on the part where it says the controller method can be empty.

When I hit the endpoint I get a Symfony exception saying:

`The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?`

I have all the necessary configs in place:

**security.yaml**

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        json_login:
            check_path: /login
```

**Controller**

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
    */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
    }
}
```

If I return something on the login endpoint, then it all works. Is this supposed to be like that, since the documentation says I don't need to return anything?

Comment: Is it because in dev you've got `security: false`? Maybe it's not getting intercepted by the listener for this reason.

Comment: nope, already changed it and nothing

Comment: what you post data? can your share it?

Comment: it's the same mentioned on the documentation I linked above: a simple json with { "username": "some_username", "password": "some_password" }